# MySQL LIKE operator with natural language search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sql-like

I am working with two tables(TABLE A and TABLE B)built by someone else. I have noticed that if i do a search with a LIKE operator on TABLE A using natural language i get results, but when i use LIKE on TABLE B i get 0 results. One peculiar thing is that TABLE B will return 1 as count result if the search query has four words e.g., `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table_A WHERE title LIKE '%Effect of previous exposure%';"`

See the following example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table_A WHERE title LIKE '%Effect of previous exposure to malaria on diabetes type 1.%';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table_B WHERE title LIKE '%Effect of previous exposure to malaria on diabetes type 1.%';

    +----------+
    | count(*) |
    +----------+
    |        0 |
    +----------+
    1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

When i run the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement i get the following results;

Table A

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=438 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Table B:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41681 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Clearly there is a difference between the table engines.

Both tables are on the same DB.What might be possibly wrong?

Comment: Because both tables may have different data, so why would the results match ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Both tables have the same data..TABLE B will only return results if the search string has 4 words

Comment: Check the `CREATE TABLE` statement for both the tables. There may be some difference there, as well there may be slight variation in the data. Since you are trying to match a very large string. Even a difference of character will cause different results.

Comment: What Madhur said. Specifically, since it doesn't work with more than 4 words, I would check if you have e.g. a double space (or some other, maybe invisible, character) directly after `exposure`.

Comment: Thanks @MadhurBhaiya and Solarflare. I have edited the question to show the difference in table engines for both tables. I guess that is where the problem lies

Comment: Can you post the actual data (so `select title from ...` as a 1:1 copy&paste)? At least the part that contains the sentence mentioned in the search query in case it is a longer text or contains sensitive information. That different charsets can play a role if your text contains very special utf8 characters, but the problem is still your data, and we cannot do more than guess right now. Also, just to clarify: for table B, you get a result for `... like '%Effect of previous exposure%'`  but not for `'... like '%Effect of previous exposure to%'`, right?

Comment: @Solarflare Yes, i get result for `... like '%Effect of previous exposure%'` but not for  `'... like '%Effect of previous exposure to%'` when i run the query in table B. Sorry, I am not able to post the data here due to legal issues but one of the results from a `SELECT title from TableB..` query  is ...`A comparative study on the prevalence of malaria parasite among HIV sero–positive and sero-negative individuals in Busia Kenya.`

Comment: The problem is in your specific data, and specifically somewhere in the 3 characters after the word `exposure` (maybe check the hex representation of your string). I cannot be more precise. If you need further help identifying the problem (or to give us an idea of what else it could be), I specifically asked for (just) the part of the result with the sentence that contains your search string, and since we already know that this sentence is part of your result, it should not have any legal issues. A random other row is unfortunately not helpful.

Comment: Sorry for all this misunderstanding. Just to clarify, i am trying to do a sql search where i expect mysql to return the exact row with the title matching the string on the query. For example, if i run the  following query `SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE title LIKE '%Effect of previous exposure to malaria on diabetes type 1.%';` I expect Mysql to find a match based on exact string....that is to return the row with the exact title `Effect of previous exposure to malaria on diabetes type 1.`

Comment: `like '%sometext%'` will do a partial match (e.g. the title contains the string `sometext`). If you want an exact match, you need `= 'sometext'`. I am not sure in what way this is related to this problem though (as you will have the same problem with `=` than with `like` if there is some mismatch in your data, like an incorrect character). Anyway, without seeing that sentence in the result of both of your queries, I really cannot help you any more, I just keep repeating what I said in my first comment 3 hours ago: check what is happening directly after `exposure`.

Comment: This is the sentence `Effect of previous exposure to malaria on diabetes type-1` There is no other text after the word type-1. This sentence is exactly the same with the one in the table field title.So i guess you are suggesting the character `-` is what is causing the problem which i highly doubt because other texts without special characters cannot  also be matched using the operator LIKE.Thank you.

Comment: This is the last time I will say this. I need the following from you (and will not comment or answer otherwise): the exact result for the query `SELECT title FROM Table_B WHERE title LIKE '%Effect of previous exposure%`' for both tables, added to the question. You can remove anything before `Effect` and after `type 1.` if it contains sensitive information. If not (or if there is nothing), also add the result of `select hex(title) from ...` for both tables. No other sentences are relevant. We know where exactly in your data the problem is. I have no clue why you now use a title about Kenya.

Comment: For table A i get `Effect of previous exposure to malaria on diabetes type-1` while for table B i get nothing as in i get blank. When i run `Select hex(title) on table A i get the following results `456666656374206F662070726576696...` while for table B i get `412070696C6F7420737475647920746F206576616C75.....`. Sorry for the communication breakdown and misunderstanding and thanks for your patience